# Why can't I compile maven with OpenJFX and Deeplearning4J?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, openjfx, gluon-desktop

I have a small issue that I don't know how to solve.
I have started a simple basic JavaFX application and my `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>se.danielmartensson</groupId>
    <artifactId>JNonlinearControl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
        <artifactId>datavec-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0-alpha0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0-alpha0</version>
   </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>se.danielmartensson.JNonlinearControl.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <mainClass>se.danielmartensson.JNonlinearControl.App</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I try to compile with

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

It works! But then I try to run

```
mvn javafx:run
```

I got these errors below.

**Question:**

Why can't I compile maven with OpenJFX and Deeplearning4J?

If you look at the errors, it looks like this:

```
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from X: Invalid module name: X is not a Java identifier
```

Log when I run `mvn javafx:run`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------< se.danielmartensson:JNonlinearControl >----------------
[INFO] Building JNonlinearControl 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) @ JNonlinearControl ---
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from protobuf-java-shaded-351-0.9.jar: protobuf.java.shaded.351: Invalid module name: '351' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-windows-x86_64.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-android-arm64.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-linux-x86_64.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-android-arm.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-linux-armhf.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from datavec-data-image-1.0.0-beta4.jar: Provider class com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi not in module
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-android-x86_64.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-api-1.0.0-beta4.jar: nd4j.native.api: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-ios-arm64.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-platform-1.0.0-beta4.jar: nd4j.native.platform: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from protobuf-java-util-shaded-351-0.9.jar: protobuf.java.util.shaded.351: Invalid module name: '351' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-ios-x86_64.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-macosx-x86_64.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-android-x86.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4-linux-ppc64le.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta4.jar: nd4j.native: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.bytedeco.openblas.linux.ppc64le not found, required by org.bytedeco.openblas.platform
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.117 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-18T02:01:42+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) on project JNonlinearControl: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Actually those are warnings (all the native jars are not modules), but not errors. The error mentions `java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.bytedeco.openblas.linux.ppc64le not found, required by org.bytedeco.openblas.platform`, so maybe you are missing a dependency?

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried to include "org.bytedeco.openblas" and "org.bytedeco.openblas-platform" but it gave the same error after I have compile it and then run it. I have heard that I need to disable the module-path. What is that? I don't have any module-info.java file in my project.

Comment: @JoséPereda You don't know?

Comment: Can you try the new JavaFX Maven plugin version 0.0.3?

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes! I will create a new project and include the latest plugin. Give me 30 minutes.

Comment: @JoséPereda It works now! But I still get the warnings "[WARNING] Can't extract module name from nd4j-native-api-1.0.0-beta4.jar: nd4j.native.api: Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier". Thank you.

Comment: Cool. There was an issue fixed in 0.0.3 possibly related to the error you were facing. About the warnings, somehow these native jars are causing some troubles when the classpath is analyzed. Can you file an issue [here](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues)?

Comment: @JoséPereda I have written an issue now.